# How to install the .MSI packages without Invoke-Command using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I’m using the following PowerShell script to install 32-bit & 64-bit .MSI packages and then write output of MSI Installer package into text file.

```
#Set Location for Log File
$LogFilePath = "C:\XXXX\Nishiketh\MSI_Installer_Logs.txt"

#Function to Add Content to Log File
Function Write-Log {
  [CmdletBinding()] 
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$LogFilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$Message
  )
 
  Process {
    #Add Message to Log File with timestamp
    "$([datetime]::Now) : $Message" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFilePath -append;
   
    #Write the log message to the screen
    Write-host $([datetime]::Now) $Message
  }
}

#Install ABC 32bit MSI package and then write logs to text file
$ABC_32Bit_Result = Invoke-Command -computername localhost -ScriptBlock { (Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i C:\temp\ABC_32bit_13_0_12.msi /quiet /norestart" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode }
if ($ABC_32Bit_Result -eq 0) { 
  Write-Log $LogFilePath "Successfully installed ABC_32bit MSI package"
}
else { 
  Write-Log $LogFilePath "Failed to install ABC_32bit MSI package"
}

#Install XYZ 64bit MSI package and then write logs to text file
$XYZ_64Bit_Result = Invoke-Command -computername localhost -ScriptBlock { (Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i C:\temp\XYZ_64bit_13_0_12.msi /quiet /norestart" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode }
if ($XYZ_64Bit_Result -eq 0) { 
  Write-Log $LogFilePath "Successfully installed XYZ_64bit MSI package"
}
else { 
  Write-Log $LogFilePath "Failed to install XYZ_64bit MSI package"
}
```

But some machines blocked to install the .MSI packages using Invoke-Command due to organizational policy.

So, I want to install the .MSI packages without Invoke-Command?

Comment: `Invoke-Command` uses WinRM just like most of PowerShell cmdlets, so if you can run something like `Get-Process -ComputerName Computer`, it's not your organization. You can try using RPC calls, or using DCOM remoting with WMI instead as a troubleshooting/alternate step.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, if possible provide the sample code snippet

Comment: Why not just launch it directly, without `Invoke-Command` in the first place? `$ABC_32Bit_Result = (Start-Process "msiexec" -ArgumentList "/i C:\temp\ABC_32bit_13_0_12.msi /quiet /norestart" -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode`

Comment: Mathias, I have tried to install MSI package using the above command. But I'm unable to install the MSI package. Because I'm getting the `Failed to install MSI package` error.